# Spring WebMVC internationalized requestmapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-web

i have to build a webapp which contains request mappings in different languages.
So for instance we would have a RequestUrl "domain.de/pkw/sommerreifen/..." for german language and if the user changes to english language it has to be "domain.de/car/summer/...". To build the paths we could simply use I18N, but i am not sure how to get all those RequestMappings defined without the risk of forgetting.

Is there a way in Spring WebMVC to solve this usecase? If not we would have to put around 100 different paths in the `@RequestMapping` annotations. This would be really annoying...

Thanks in advance

Christian